# Create form of Category with SubCategories on Symfony

Tags: database, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have two entities : Category and SubCategory. One category have 0 or many subcategory. They are related with Many-to-One relation.
I don't imagine how i can make a form with subcategories group by category like this :

```
CATEGORY 1 :
- SubCategory 1
- SubCategory 2
CATEGORY 2:
- SubCategory 1
- SubCategory 2
```

My form actual :

```
class CategorieType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
    * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param array $options
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sous_categories', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => SousCategorie::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
            ))
        ;
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you detail a bit more what you want to do with your form ? Is it a POST, PUT, you just want to link entities ?

Comment: I have an entity Company who's related with SubCategory with relation Many-To-Many, so i want add SubCategories to a Company

Comment: Use `EntityType` with group_by option https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by

Comment: Thank you, suddenly I get my categories but how to parser in twig to display sub categories?

Answer (score 0):

I do that in my form, i obtein the subcategories. How to show them grouped in box by category ?

```
$builder
        ->add('sous_categories', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'    => 'AppBundle:Bdd\SousCategorie',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($revue) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
                    ->addSelect('sc')
                    ->join('sc.Categorie', 'c')
                    ->andWhere('c.Revue = :Revue')
                    ->setParameter('Revue', $revue)
                    ->orderBy('c.libelle', 'ASC')
                    ->addOrderBy('sc.libelle', 'ASC')
                ;
            },
            'choice_label' => function($sousCategorie){
                return $sousCategorie->getCategorie()->getLibelle()." - ".$sousCategorie->getLibelle();
            },
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ))
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  a groupBy in you repository function :

```
$builder
        ->add('sous_categories', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'    => 'AppBundle:Bdd\SousCategorie',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($revue) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('sc')
                    ->addSelect('sc')
                    ->join('sc.Categorie', 'c')
                    ->andWhere('c.Revue = :Revue')
                    ->setParameter('Revue', $revue)
                    ->orderBy('c.libelle', 'ASC')
                    ->addOrderBy('sc.libelle', 'ASC')
                    ->groupBy('sc.Categorie')
                ;
            },
            'choice_label' => function($sousCategorie){
                return $sousCategorie->getCategorie()->getLibelle()." - ".$sousCategorie->getLibelle();
            },
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ))
    ;
```

Comment: Hi Antoine, i tried this but now i obtain this error from mysql :SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fitadata.b0_.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: J'ai réussi en désactivant le mode only_full_group_by (http://www.cipherbliss.com/comment-desactiver-de-facon-permanente-le-mode-only-full-group-by-de-mysql/) mais par contre après comment afficher tout ca correctement dans twig ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you, so I solved it based on the previous answers! Although it's been six years since your question, I hope it helps someone who has the same problem.

```
        ->add('subCategory', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => SubCategory::class,
            'group_by' => function($subcategory) {
                return $subcategory->getCategory()->getName();
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($subcategory) {
                return $subcategory->getName();
            },
        ])
```