# Symfony 5 Category and subcategory in optgroup

Tags: php, symfony

I need in a form to display in an input sub-categories listed by parent category.

My category table is presented like this:

id parent_id title

---

1  0         Fêtes

2  0         Foires

3  0         Sport

4  1         Fêtes Locales

5  1         Carnavals

6  2         Salons

7  2         Expositions

8  3         Tournois

9  3         Courses

I did this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => "Catégorie de l'événement *",
            'class' => Category::class,
            'group_by' => function($category) {
                $category = $this->entityManager->find(Category::class, $category->getParentId());
                return $category->getTitle();
            },
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->Where('c.parentId != 0');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'title',
            'help' => 'Choisissez ensuite la catégorie définissant le mieux votre événement.',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'filter-input'],
        ])
    ;
}
```

And I have this result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZxA3.png)

I would like to be able to add the parent categories as a choice of categories.

So something like:

### Fêtes

- *Add >* **Fêtes**
- Fêtes locales
- Carnavals
- etc

### Foires

- *Add >* **Foires**
- Salons
- Expositions
- Etc

Is there a way to do this without passing an array to the form? Directly at the buildForm or associated class?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO @yinyang. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802530/symfony-form-category-subcategory) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197407/create-form-of-category-with-subcategories-on-symfony) answer your question?

Comment: EntityType doesn't really support adding, and it's also inconvenient at times, especially if you want one add-form for each category.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant no, he use group_by and I already use group_by, I just need to add the parent categories in the list to be able to select them, and I would'nt use Symfony extension as possible.